# Grammar: For vs to?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, to-for

In my mother tongue both **for** and **to** have the same meaning, therefore it is hard for (is it being correctly used here?) me to know when I should use one instead of the other.
After some google's searches into the question I verified that the former must be used when we want to refer to a **purpose** or when something is to the **benefit of** somebody.
The latter is used when something is **moved** or **transferred** between locations or in the direction of a location.

For instance:

> We are going to open this plan **for** public discussion **to** individuals and organizations interested in maintaining and advancing Thunderbird in the future.

In the above sentence I'm still unable to understand why we use those prepositions; can anyone help on the subject?

Comment: Prepositions are little words with many meanings, often overlapping.  This sentence is a good example of that; you could swap the 'for' and 'to' and the sentence would essentially mean the same thing.

Comment: _It is hard for me to know_ is not a usage of either preposition; theyre [infinitive complementizers](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/complmnt.html). _For_ marks the subject and _to_ marks the verb of an infinitive clause. This has nothing to do with any other meaning of _for_ or _to_. For instance. As J.R. says, there are many meanings, often overlapping -- but sometimes not, as here.

Comment: John, are you saying that **for** here is not being used as a preposition ?

Answer (score 4):

First, if you really want to compare and contrast those two, of course you have to start by making your examples parallel.

For instance, both "for" and "to" are used to talk about purpose:

> 1. I went to the supermarket **to** buy oranges.
> 2. I went to the supermarket **for** oranges.
> 3. A knife is used **for** cutting.

Now, you can start looking into how they differ.

Second, be careful not to mix up Infinitives, Prepositions that are part of Phrasal Verbs, and Prepositions that just often go together with the Verbs. Because if you consider all these simultaneously (like what you're doing in your question above), you won't be able to make sense of things.

Just a few examples:

> 1. We are looking forward **to** meeting you.
> 2. He went **to** them.
> 3. I bought the gift **for** my mother.
> 4. He threw the ball **to** me.
> 5. I am looking **for** the supervisor.
> 6. I am planning **for** a trip.

Of course all these are valid examples, but there are different and separate ways of learning them.

Answer (score 0):

I think you've already answered your own question.  However, I wish to point out that (while technically incorrect) I have always found the colloquial use of both together to be quite charming.  "What is the use of putting all of this effort in for to understand, anyway?  You still know what I mean."   :P