# What is the the right way to say "for user" or "to user"

Tags: to-for

What is the the right way to say(for or to)?

```
Private message from John `for` Jake
```

or

```
Private message from John `to` Jake
```

Comment: From John to Jake.  This question would be more appropriate for our sister site http://ell.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prepositions like 'for' and 'to' always have a painful number of specific situations in which they are conventionally used, and ***general rules are not much help.***

> Private message from John `to` Jake appears **more idiosyncratic** than from John `for` Jake.

But opinions could vary.

Some identifiers, if not prescriptive rules are:

**TO:** Used to indicate the place, person, or thing that someone or something moves toward, or the direction of something,can also be used to refer to time:

```
      Please send it back to me. 
      She played the piano from ten to twelve.
```

**FOR:** Used to indicate the use of something/used to mean because of, to indicate time or duration:

```
     I put a note on the door for privacy.
     I am so happy for you. 
     This is all I have for today.
```

Reference- [idiosyncratic](http://www.talkenglish.com/Grammar/prepositions-of-to-for.aspx) and [ELU-Prepositions are words with many meanings, often overlapping.](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/74005/grammar-for-vs-to)