# Why do certain verbs not agree with the preposition "for"?

Tags: prepositions, present-progressive

These two sentences seem the same to me:

> *I watch it for practicing English (wrong)
>
> I use it for practicing English

But the first seems wrong while the other is fine.  Do "Watch" or "Listen to it" (which also seems wrong) have some kind of special rules about how they work with "for"?

Comment: It's apparently because it merely fails to make sense -- you don't watch for practicing -- you practice by watching/ you watch for practice. HTH.

Comment: That's what I thought at first, but "I listen to it for practicing english" also doesn't sound correct to me.

Comment: Assuming that 'it' is a TV programme, I would say "I watch it so as to practise English".

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with either as it does make sense: For is "used when we want to refer to a purpose or when something is to the benefit of somebody".* He watches [it] in the hopes of reaping benefits from it, such as improving his English. * http://www.englishandculture.com/blog/bid/95563/Quick-English-Grammar-Tip-To-Versus-For

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/74005/grammar-for-vs-to

Comment: With other topics, “for practicing” would mean “to (help me) practice”. Here, “for” is beside the point and both examples are wrong because of the meanings of “practice” and “English”.

You could as well, grammatically, "watch for practicing" as "practice by watching" but this is purely about the meaning of the word "practice, which can't be passive - unless what you're practicing is for instance, relaxation.

You can "study" or "improve your” English by reading or listening but that's not practice. Again, you "practice" English only by speaking English.